# How to find out the Notification channel Id from RemoteMessage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo

I registered notification channel in Android app following GoogleSamples https://github.com/googlesamples/android-NotificationChannels

However how can I get notification channel Id from RemoteMessage, so I can set it to NotificationBuilder.

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) 
{
//int id = remoteMessage.getNotificationChannel(); // -something like this I could not find
}
```

I found this value in RemoteMessage object

[image]

value[3]="notification_channel_system", so I can set the value to firebase push notification using key value `android_channel_id` https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref but I cannot get it when it is received by device.

How does one get this id from PushNotification and set it to notification builder?

Comment: Is the `notification_channel_system` something fron your payload? Or were you just debugging and founf these value in RemoteMessage?

Comment: It is my payload, which I inserted in firebase notification console into text field "Android Notification Channel", so I am sure channel data comes from right place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 17.4.0, there is an official API to get it, see Marko Gajić's [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55417644).

### Outdated Answer

The `RemoteMessage` object does contain the channel within its `Bundle`, however `getData()` strips out anything that starts with, among other things, `gcm.`. Unfortunately, this includes the channel key, which is `gcm.notification.android_channel_id`.

For my purposes when the push notification is received when the app is in the foreground, I still wanted to display it in the system, using the channel id that was sent from the server.

I'm able to achieve this (admittedly a bit hacky) with a simple two-line file:

```
package com.google.firebase.messaging

fun RemoteMessage.getChannel() : String? = zzds.getString("gcm.notification.android_channel_id")
```

Comment: Interesting. This sounds a good enough solution at the moment. However, this may run into some problems if Google decides to change where the data is (like putting it in a different class) -- which makes calling the (I presume obfuscated) class (`zzds`) cause a crash in the future -- requiring a force update for users where the app handles the newer one.

Comment: Yeah, it's for sure fragile, and would need to be altered if the library were re-packaged/re-obfuscated. Fortunately the firebase messaging dependency is packaged with the app. I think a dependency update would just give you a compile error, and could be resolved in the same app release.

Comment: Sure enough a new version of `firebase-messaging` was released with a different obfuscation. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 13):

See [`getChannelId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.Notification#getChannelId()):

> Gets the channel id from the notification. Note that this method does not perform verification on the existence of a channel, nor does it fallback to the manifest defined default or the default FCM channel.
>
> Returns channel id that was provided when the message was sent, null otherwise.

---

Did some digging with Android Notification Channels in relation with FCM and here's what I got:

There is currently no function to get the notification channel id (*aka* `android_channel_id` or from your post -- `notification_channel_system`). AFAICT, this is working as intended. Since the notification channel id included in the payload from FCM *should* be handled automatically by the client. From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) (emphasis mine):

> The [notification's channel id](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/notification-channels.html) (new in Android O).
>
> **The app must create a channel with this ID before any notification with this key is received.**
>
> If you don't send this key in the request, or if the channel id provided has not yet been created by your app, FCM uses the channel id specified in your app manifest.

Which means you have to [create the notification channel ids](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateChannel) that you intend to use *first* -- what I did was create the notification channels in the application instance, like so:

```
private void initNotificationChannels() {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    String channelIdOne = "com.my.fcm.test.app.test_channel_one";
    CharSequence nameOne = getString(R.string.channel_one_name);
    String descriptionOne = getString(R.string.channel_one_description);
    int importanceOne = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

    NotificationChannel channelOne = new NotificationChannel(channelIdOne, nameOne, importanceOne);
    channelOne.setDescription(descriptionOne);
    channelOne.enableLights(true);
    channelOne.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
    channelOne.enableVibration(false);
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channelOne);

    String channelIdTwo = "com.my.fcm.test.app.test_channel_two";
    CharSequence nameTwo = getString(R.string.channel_two_name);
    String descriptionTwo = getString(R.string.channel_two_description);
    int importanceTwo = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

    NotificationChannel channelTwo = new NotificationChannel(channelIdTwo, nameTwo, importanceTwo);
    // Configure the notification channel.
    channelTwo.setDescription(descriptionTwo);
    channelTwo.enableVibration(false);
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channelTwo);
}
```

So that when the payload comes in, the client itself *should* handle it accordingly.

Comment: notification data channel should be included in Notification payload, not in data payload.

Comment: @Malbac Riiight. I thought you added in a custom. I'll do some testing and will get back here with an edit if I manage to get it.

Comment: @Malbac Done with the edit. I think that's about it. Let me know if something's not clear. Cheers!

Comment: You're right but you're missing the point. When we receive the notification when the app is in the background everything works great as you say. However, if we receive the notification when the app is in the foreground, there's currently no way to know what is the notification channel. What if I want to trigger a local notification to mimic the behavior when the app is in the background? What if I want to do different stuff based on the channel? Right now there's simply no way to do any of that simply becase `RemoteMessage` doesn't externalize the notification channel.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula I did say I think it was working as intended. The use cases you pointed out are understandable, and as you said, the limitation is on `RemoteMessage` itself. So I believe my answer is still on point since it explains the current (*only*) way the FCM android channel id works. With that said, you could file for a feature request to have this feature for FCM.

Comment: Yup, I've done that. It's unfortunate I can't track my feature request, though. For now we're sending the notification channel in the custom data payload too in order to access it when we receive a notification while the app is in the foreground.

Answer (score 2):

Since Cloud Messaging version 17.4.0, RemoteMessage.Notification class has been extended with the [getChannelId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.Notification.html#getChannelId()) method, so this is now officially supported.

From the Firebase Release Notes:

> **Cloud Messaging version 17.4.0**
>
> Added getChannelId method to RemoteMessage.Notification for getting the channel ID set in a notification message.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```java
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) 
{
    String id = remoteMessage.getNotification().getChannelId()
}
```